# Detox: How to pass -disableRNTestingOverride 1 parameter

Tags: ios, react-native, detox

I'm using detox on the newest version and this commit (https://github.com/wix/Detox/commit/2507c1e4325936ed9f46c0f64571fa581c71ff5f) disabled the IS_TESTING field for our tests.

It mentions that we have to pass -disableRNTestingOverride 1 to disable this behavior, where do we have to set this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it as a launch argument to `device.launchApp()`, as shown [here](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DeviceObjectAPI.md#7-additional-launch-arguments).

```
await device.launchApp({launchArgs: {disableRNTestingOverride: 1}});
```